# Is it possible to connect to any android device on the same network over wifi using adb command?

Tags: android, wifi, adb

Is it possible to connect and access to any android device on the same network over wifi using adb command:

adb connect

Comment: Yes. As long as the device acknowledges it.

Answer (score -2):

If phone is rooted then its possible. Otherwise you have to use 3rd party application for that.

Comment: Why do we need root access?

Comment: I have tried to do it with my unrooted device but didnt get success. But with rooted device it works well.

Comment: Works on all of my un-rooted devices.

Comment: Root is not necessary for wireless adb, but you do have to connect the device with USB first.

Comment: But he is talking about wifi.

Comment: My device is connected to wifi and to my PC with USB cable. My PC is not connected to wifi. I tried to connect adb using 'adb connect <ip>'. But it shows 'unable to connect to 10.0.0.7:5555: cannot connect to 10.0.0.7:5555: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (10051)'